# Server getting stuck while upgrading from ESX 3.5i to ESX3.5

Tags: vmware-esx, vmware-esxi

i am getting the following error while upgrading the server from ESX3.5i to ESX3.5.. and the server gets Stuck.

it says :

Starting System Management Homepage:.......ok

Starting HP Insight Manager Agents: ipmi_si : servching for PCI device 0x3302
ipmi_si : Trying "Kcs" at memory address 0xf7ef....
ipmi_si : Found PCI BMC at BAR address 0xf7ef....
In try_get_dev_id

And the server gets stuck, had anyone seen this and how to resolve this?

Thanks,
Amit

Answer (score 1):

You cannot upgrade from ESXi to ESX. 
Check this [link](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&externalId=1006089&sliceId=1&docTypeID=DT_KB_1_1&dialogID=17720900&stateId=1%200%2017724513) for some suggestions when you need to repair or install any ESX(i) server:

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can upgrade from free ESX edition to paid one. You have to install over